# child elements text in a floating div breaks

Tags: html, css

not sure what i'm missing, but here ti go's:
i have a floating left div with a child div that is positioned absolutely to the bottom, but the text in the child div breaks twice:

```
<div class="imgDes"><p class="toBot">this is a test</p></div>​
```

css

```
.imgDes {
float:left;
position:relative;
height: 100px;

}

.toBot {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0px;

}​
```

here it is in action: http://jsfiddle.net/rz5Q8/
how can i keep the text inside from breaking to the next line?

Comment: 3 answers all saying what I was writing, http://jsfiddle.net/rz5Q8/1/ has updates to show

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Floating elements need a specified width. Curently "imgDes" has a width of zero. Give it a width and all will be well.

Putting borders on your elements is a good way to see what's going on:

```
.imgDes {
    float:left;
    position:relative;
    height: 100px;
    width:300px;
    border:1px solid #000000
}

.toBot {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0px;
    border:1px solid #ff0000

}
```

Comment: Adding borders makes it obvious. It's a good first step in debugging CSS.

Comment: actually i ment the width thing, i usually do background-color for debugging css, but to each there own :)

Answer (score 1):

if you give the .imgDes a width it will work:  `width: 100%;`

One way to debug this type issue is to give the container and the element inside borders of differing color (lime and red for example) - as you see in this instance the length of the text "this" gave it the appearence of a width of that text by default (really a width of 0 of the parent container).

Answer (score 1):

You need to specify a `width` on the parent element:

```
.imgDes {
  float: left;
  position: relative;
  height: 100px;
  width: 200px;
 }

 .toBot {
   position: absolute;
   bottom: 0;
 }​
```